# Spring Batch Job Repository in Oracle Database

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Am learning Spring Batch and in the process of creating a POC which would read records from MS SQL database table and load into Oracle database table. I would like to keep Oracle as Spring Batch Job Repository.

Request you to provide inputs for the following.

1) Where can I find DB Scripts for setting up Job Repository in Oracle database?

2) Is it something I need to handover to DBA Team to execute them ?

3) Does this POC need to be deployed in an application server? Or is it something I can execute through Eclipse itself?

4) What changes I need to perform in order to have the same POC work in JSR-352 libraries of jdk1.8 ( without using Spring batch )?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am aware of only 3 questions that you have posted

1) Where can I find DB Scripts for setting up Job Repository in Oracle database?
Ans : you can find the DB Scripts in  spring-batch-core-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
with the name 
1)schema-drop-oracle10g.sql  - In order to drop the tables.
2)schema-oracle10g.sql    - In order to create the tables.

2) Is it something I need to handover to DBA Team to execute them ?
Ans : If you have a client like SqlDeveloper,Command Line SQL you can execute them.If you do not have access to create new tables better hand over to DBA Team.

3) Does this POC need to be deployed in an application server? Or is it something I can execute through Eclipse itself?

Ans : You can run this from Eclipse it self by choosing like Run Configurations.
you need to configure your main method from "org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner"

Comment: Thanks Yusuf Mohammed for your inputs.

**  Yes. I am able to execute myself schema-oracle10g.sql into database. 

** Can you tell me how the pom.xml needs to be when Oracle 10g database is used for job repository?

** Also, I do not see any scripts for Oracle 11g inside the release.jar. That means Spring Batch 3.x does not still support Oracle 11g database for setting up the job repository?

Comment: You can use scripts for 10g with 11g